# gdb/gdb multiarch does not work on my ubuntu

Tags: gdb

currently I'm running xv6 on qemu on Ubuntu machine, the version is buster/sid
On one terminal I start qemu like this, seems ok

```
~/xv6-labs-2020# make qemu-gdb
*** Now run 'gdb' in another window.
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0 -S -gdb tcp::25000
```

A series of question came up here:

```
~/xv6-labs-2020# gdb-multiarch
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1.1-0ubuntu1) 8.1.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
warning: File "/root/xv6-labs-2020/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
        add-auto-load-safe-path /root/xv6-labs-2020/.gdbinit
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
        set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/root/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
        info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
(gdb) target remote:25000
Remote debugging using :25000
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
Truncated register 37 in remote 'g' packet
(gdb) file kernel/kernel
Architecture of file not recognized.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel
/bin/bash: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/bin/bash: /root/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/kernel: Success
During startup program exited with code 126.
(gdb)
```

I'm totally new to gdb and qemu, so any idea how to fix it??

Comment: I don't understand your reference to Buster/sid.  Buster is the codename of Debian *stable* (10), whilst Sid is the codename for packages that haven't yet made it into Bullseye (11) but are on their way there... Neither of which relate to Ubuntu...

Comment: sorry, Buster/sid is the result from /etc/debian-version, I forgot whether my machine is Ubuntu 18 or 20, at least not 16

Comment: 18, 20 or 16?  So this is a Ubuntu Core (*snap* only) release?, and not a *deb* based *yy.mm* release.  Ubuntu uses *yy* format for different products to the standard *yy.mm* products, so you should be specific you're using a *specialist* release.